aiogram - не выводится картинка
Написал бота в тг, который принимает данные от пользователя и посылает данные в чат саппорта. Столкнулся с проблемой.
Сам код:
dp.message(Send.q1)
async def q1(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(q1=message.text)
    username = message.from_user.username
    await state.update_data(username=username)
    await state.set_state(Send.q12)
    await message.answer('Введите вашу проблему.', reply_markup=kb.markup3)
@dp.message(Send.q12)
async def q12(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    **await state.update_data(q12=message.photo)**
    data = await state.get_data()
    await message.answer(f"{data['q1']}\n\n{message.text}\n\n<b>Проверьте правильность введенных данных.</b>", reply_markup=kb.markup4)
    await state.set_state(Send.q2)

Выделил кусок кода, где есть ошибка, после чего мне выводится в чат саппорта такое сообщение:
    - Текст заявки:
    [PhotoSize(file_id='AgACAgIAAxkBAAPwZm1pcxZimGH8Yx5AsBKFyDyGHQkAApTZMRuwZGhLJml- 
    NGbGvp8BAAMCAANzAAM1BA', file_unique_id='AQADlNkxG7BkaEt4', width=90, height=56, 
    file_size=1637), 
    PhotoSize(file_id='AgACAgIAAxkBAAPwZm1pcxZimGH8Yx5AsBKFyDyGHQkAApTZMRuwZGhLJml- 
    NGbGvp8BAAMCAANtAAM1BA', file_unique_id='AQADlNkxG7BkaEty', width=320, height=200, 
    file_size=27566), 
    PhotoSize(file_id='AgACAgIAAxkBAAPwZm1pcxZimGH8Yx5AsBKFyDyGHQkAApTZMRuwZGhLJml- 
    NGbGvp8BAAMCAAN4AAM1BA', file_unique_id='AQADlNkxG7BkaEt9', width=800, height=500, 
    file_size=141938), 
    PhotoSize(file_id='AgACAgIAAxkBAAPwZm1pcxZimGH8Yx5AsBKFyDyGHQkAApTZMRuwZGhLJml- 
    NGbGvp8BAAMCAAN5AAM1BA', file_unique_id='AQADlNkxG7BkaEt-', width=1280, height=800, 
    file_size=290463)]

Нужно сделать так, чтобы в чат выводилась картинка, а не просто текст.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос, начните с заголовка.
